# Why can I change the type of a variable in separate IHaskell Notebook cells?

Tags: haskell, types, casting, ihaskell

If I define

```
data Thing = Shoe
           | Ship
           | SealingWax
           | Cabbage
           | King
```

and then in a later cell in an IHaskell Notebook enter

```
thing :: Thing
thing = 4
```

I get an error ("No instance for (Num Thing) arising from the literal ‘4’") as expected. But if I first complete a valid binding with

```
thing :: Thing
thing = King
```

and then later, in a separate cell make the same (invalid) assignment with

```
thing = 4
```

I get no error, and `t: thing` yields `thing :: (Num a) => a`.

More perplexingly, if I put

```
thing = Cabbage
:t thing
thing = 5
:t thing
```

in a single cell I get no errors and

```
thing :: Thing
thing :: (Num a) => a
```

but a single cell without the `:t` lines

```
thing = Cabbage
thing = 5
```

gives an error:

```
Multiple declarations of ‘thing’
Declared at: :1:1
             :2:1
```

Why can I change the type of a variable in separate IHaskell Notebook cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Haskell, you *can't* change or reassign variables. What you're doing is declaring a *new* variable that just reuses the *name* `shoe`, but is otherwise entirely distinct.

Your second definition of `show` **shadows** the first because it takes the same name, but it doesn't affect it in any other way.

The single-cell example is a bit more confusing: essentially, a `:t` separates the cell into multiple definitions. With the `:t`, it's as if you had two cells; without it, it's as if you simultaneously tried to define `x` in two different ways—which wouldn't have worked even if they had the same type.

In general, shadowing names in Haskell is a bit awkward and not good style. You can even enable a warning about it:

```
:set -fwarn-name-shadowing
```

It can also be turned on as part of a larger suite of warnings:

```
:set -Wall
```

Comment: So perhaps the question then is why I'm prevented from shadowing in some cases and allowed in others (see edit above) .

Comment: And: Is there way to configure Haskell to warn about shadowing?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Yep. I was about to add that to my answer :). You can turn on the `-fwarn-name-shadowing` flag: `:set -fwarn-name-shadowing`. That works from `ghci` for sure and *probably* works from IHaskell, but I don't have it running locally to test.

Comment: Cool. I'll see if I can set up IHaskell to do that (maybe a new question).

Comment: So, to be clear: What looks like (coming from other languages) *assignment* is in fact *definition*? Doing `thing = 5` after `thing = King` doesn't attempt to assign `5` to the existing `thing` but creates something new? If so, what about `thing = Ship` after `thing = King`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Yep, it's always definition, never assignment. It's a bit less obvious in a setting like IHaskell because the normally static change of defining a new value with the same name happens interactively.

Comment: And that's true even if the types match (as in `thing = Ship` after `thing = King`): `King` is still around, just shadowed by `Ship`, right?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Yep. It would be inconsistent otherwise.